# An new monitor cable messed up my resolution

Tags: resolution, monitor, vga

I was having trouble with the old VGA cable I was using for my monitor. So I got a new one off of Amazon real cheap, it says it's High Res HD15 on the posting I got it from. However when I boot into Kubuntu or Ubuntu, the resolution is wayyyyyyy too low and the proper one is not appearing in the settings. Also, the GRUB menu is a different color (dark blue vs. light blue) and the resolution is smaller.

The proper resolution is displayed in Windows.

Is there any way to fix this? do I have to buy a new cable?

Comment: OK, thank you, but I was able to get the appropriate resolution and performance when I replaced the cable without turning off the computer when I first got the new cable. Also, when I remove the nVidia driver I can get up to 1024x768 which is a little less than what I need. The nVidia settings say I have a CRT, and they won't show me layout options because the current default is 640x480.

Comment: I have now tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers with APT, and also from the nvidia website which has left Kubuntu entirely unbootable, with my monitor saying "out of range" after a garbled splash screen.

Answer (score 2):

Few options/ideas:

- *Good* VGA cables are not expensive. For about £20 you can buy a [2m, triple-shielded Lindy cable](http://www.cableuniverse.co.uk/lindy-premium-gold-vga-cable-2-metres.html).
- Good monitors aren't much more, to be fair and will give you much more value than a diamond-encrusted VGA cable. There's a reason DVI and HDMI replaced VGA: they're better.
- Get somebody else to test the cable in their set up.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a bit easy, but have you tried changing resolution back to normal from the Monitors menu. I had an issue with my 64bit Linux Mint once where it would automatically lower the resolution whenever graphic shaders are executed (games)...

Either way I don't trust 64bit Ubuntus anymore....